# JSch's ChannelSftp doesn't download more than one file at a time

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

It's too frustrating that JSch doesn't throw exceptions with decent messages. I'm trying to download a set of files as InputStreams. The code to download the file is pretty simple:

```java
  @Override
  @SneakyThrows
  public InputStream getInputStream(String path) {
    return channelSftp.get(path);
  }
```

I have this list of file URLs that I'm using to download InputStream and convert it to DataPages:

```java
    List<DataPage> dataPages =
        files.stream()
            .map(
                fileName -> {
                  String fileURL = folderUrl[0] + "/" + fileName;
                  return client.getInputStream(fileURL);
                })
            .map(dataPageFunction)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The first file is downloaded successfully. The problem occurs when we get the second file. I enabled log to discover if I find out anything, but the only thing I got is:

> 2022-04-13T10:58:27.916Z  INFO [Connect thread localhost session] i.s.c.e.c.SftpClient$JschLogger:158 Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed

I tried a different way to get files:

```java
  @SneakyThrows
  public Stream<InputStream> getInputStreams(String folderURL, String filePattern) {
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> lsEntries = channelSftp.ls(folderURL + "/" + filePattern);
    return lsEntries.stream()
        .map(
            entry -> {
              Optional<InputStream> is = Optional.empty();
              try {
                is = Optional.of(channelSftp.get(folderURL + "/" + entry.getFilename()));
              } catch (SftpException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
              }
              return is;
            })
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get);
  }
```

And as noticed previously, the first file was downloaded successfully. There were three files in total, the `channelSftp.get` method failed for second and third file.

The printed logs were:

```
2022-04-13T12:08:06.864Z ERROR [Test worker] i.s.c.e.c.SftpClient:132 
2022-04-13T12:08:08.316Z ERROR [Test worker] i.s.c.e.c.SftpClient:132
```

and the stack trace was nothing but:

```
4: 
    at app//com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2227)
    at app//com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2242)
    at app//com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1592)
    at app//com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1553)
.
.
.
```

I'd like to include my `open` and `close` config just incase:

```java
  @SneakyThrows
  public void open() {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    JSch.setLogger(new JschLogger());
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(privateKey)) {
      privateKey = SSHUtils.toRSA(privateKey, passphrase);
      jsch.addIdentity(
          "",
          privateKey.getBytes(),
          null,
          Objects.nonNull(passphrase) ? passphrase.getBytes() : null);
    }

    session = jsch.getSession(username, server, Objects.nonNull(port) ? port : DEFAULT_PORT);
    session.setConfig(config);
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(password)) session.setPassword(password);
    session.connect();
    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    channelSftp.connect();
  }

  @SneakyThrows
  public void close() {
    if (Objects.nonNull(channelSftp) && channelSftp.isConnected()) channelSftp.disconnect();
    if (Objects.nonNull(session) && session.isConnected()) session.disconnect();
  }
```

Comment: *...and the stack trace was nothing but:...* Isn't that indicating that a download wasn't even started on those entries?

Comment: @g00se so what's going wrong here?

Comment: First, I know little about Java streams. But I'd guess that their use of the streams is somehow incompatible with JSch. Are you aware that JSch is not thread safe? Isn't that the problem? Isn't each stream processed in a different thread? Did you try to narrow down the problem? What if you use simple sequential test code to open a stream, process it and then go on with another file? What if you then open multiple streams  and process them in parallel, in one thread? Would that still work? Maybe JSch even have problems with too many opened parallel streams (though I believe that it should work)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Maybe a bad url? Then you'd have to ask why one works and not the others. If you can make that code runnable and standalone, I'll test it. I'm not quite sure why you call it `getInputStreams` if you're doing an (s)ftp get, but I'll check the javadocs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned that JSch doesn't go that well with streams. This problem can be fixed by simply looping over `lsEntries`.

```java
  @SneakyThrows
  public List<InputStream> getInputStreams(String folderURL, String filePattern) {
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> lsEntries = channelSftp.ls(folderURL + "/" + filePattern);
    List<InputStream> inputStreams = new ArrayList<>();
    for (LsEntry entry : lsEntries) {
      try {
        inputStreams.add(channelSftp.get(folderURL + "/" + entry.getFilename()));
      } catch (SftpException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
    return inputStreams;
  }
```